# How to retrieve data according to user's unique number('staff_id')?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 columns of information，*check in* and *check out* columns. I filled in these 2 columns by retrieving data from attendance_records_table. Below are the code to retrieve data from the table,

```
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
   @php
   $no = 1
   @endphp
@foreach ($user as $row)
   <tr>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $no++ }} </div>
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->staff_id }} </div>
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->name }} </div>
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
     <div class="text-sm text-gray-900"> {{ $row->email }} </div>
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
     {{ $row->Department->department ?? null }}
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
     {{ $row->company_name }}
     </td>

     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <a href="users/profile/{{ $row->id }}"> View profile </a></td>

     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
     @php
     $latestRecord = App\Models\AttendanceRecord::orderBy('created_at', 
     'desc')->first();
     @endphp
                                
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> 
     {{$latestRecord -> date_checkIn }} <br>
     {{$latestRecord -> time_checkIn }} <br>
     {{$latestRecord -> location_checkIn }}
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <br>
     {{$latestRecord -> time_checkOut }} <br>
     {{$latestRecord -> location_checkOut }}
     </td>

     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <a 
     href="/users/profile/edit/{{ $row->id }}"> Edit </a></td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
</tbody>
```

The problem now is that it is updating all the *check in* and *check out* column with the same information no matter who the person is. How can I make it specific to *staff_id* number? Here I attach 2 screenshot so that you can understand the situation better. https://paste.pics/f4f994f575051e31d3b5d39371a4a54b, https://paste.pics/8ab5293c4830c84e271d48c10c152149

I updated the information through postman, here are the 2 controllers for clock in and clock out :

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

        $users->save();

        // Retrieve the current data
        $currentData = $users->toArray();

        // Store current data into attendance record table
        $attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
        $attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
        $attendanceRecord->save();

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }


public function userClockOut(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'time_checkOut', 'location_checkOut'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkOut = $time;
        $users->location_checkOut = $r->location_checkOut;

        // Save the updated data to the database
        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Comment: How do you update these records?

Comment: @Jaquarh i update these record through postman, i just add the 2 controllers for that in my post

Comment: @brombeer isn't it supposed to be post parameter ? since I'll fetch the data from front-end(flutter) ...for the WHERE clause, is it like this ? $latestRecord = App\Models\AttendanceRecord::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where(['staff_id'])->first(); ?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't provide that information, just a blade file. So it's a POST parameter then. `->where(['staff_id'])` You already have a working `where` clause in your controller code, why not use the same format?